# How to call a class within a function definition in c++

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor, destructor

Its my first time asking for help on programming. I have been working on a register program for my programming class for weeks which involves classes. Its rather frustrating for me. I have to use two classes: StoreItem and Register. StoreItem deals with the small list of items that the store sells. The register class deals mostly with processing the items, making a total bill and asking the user to pay with cash.
Here is the StoreItem.cpp file:

```
//function definition
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "StoreItem.h"
#include "Register.h"
using namespace std;

StoreItem::StoreItem(string , double)
{
    //sets the price of the current item
    MSRP;
}
void StoreItem::SetDiscount(double)
{
    // sets the discount percentage
    MSRP * Discount;
}
double StoreItem::GetPrice()
{   // return the price including discounts
    return Discount * MSRP;
}
double StoreItem::GetMSRP()
{
    //returns the msrp
    return MSRP;
}
string StoreItem::GetItemName()
{
    //returns item name
    return ItemName;
}
StoreItem::~StoreItem()
{
    //deletes storeitem when done
}
```

Here is the Register.cpp:
Note that the last 5 function definitions in this one arent finished yet...

```
// definition of the register header
#include "Register.h"
#include "StoreItem.h"
using namespace std;

Register::Register()
{   // sets the initial cash in register to 400
    CashInRegister = 400;
}
Register::Register(double)
{   //accepts initial specific amount
    CashInRegister ;
}
void Register::NewTransAction()
{   //sets up the register for a new customer transaction (1 per checkout)
    int NewTransactionCounter = 0;
    NewTransactionCounter++;
}
void Register::ScanItem(StoreItem)
{   // adds item to current transaction
    StoreItem.GetPrice();
// this probably isnt correct....

}
double Register::RegisterBalance()
{   
    // returns the current amount in the register
}
double Register::GetTransActionTotal()
{
    // returns total of current transaction
}
double Register::AcceptCash(double)
{
    // accepts case from customer for transaction. returns change
}
void Register::PrintReciept()
{
    // Prints all the items in the transaction and price when finsished

}
Register::~Register()
{
    // deletes register
}
```

My main question is where Register::ScanItem(StoreItem)... is there a way to correctly call a function from the storeItem Class into the Register scanitem function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
void Register::ScanItem(StoreItem)
{   // adds item to current transaction
    StoreItem.GetPrice();
// this probably isnt correct....

}
```

This means that the `ScanItem` function takes one argument of type `StoreItem`. In C++ you can specify just the type and make the compiler happy. But if you intend to use the argument, you must give it a name. For example:

```
void Register::ScanItem(StoreItem item)
{
    std::cout << item.GetItemName() << " costs " << item.GetPrice() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to call a member function of the object you're passing as the parameter, you need to name the parameter, not just its type.

I suspect you want something like

```
void Register::ScanItem(StoreItem item)
{
    total += item.GetPrice();
}
```